# How to browse files in blackberry using a program

Tags: blackberry, filesystems

I want to write a program that launches the blackberry's home screen and then browse the file i required and when i click on import option i want to retrieve the path of that selected file. Is it possible in blackberry? if yes please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FilePicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/FilePicker.html) (ignoring the "launches the blackberry's home screen" part of your question which isn't very clear).

If FilePicker is not working for you, find a way to open the built-in Media app which has an Explore menu to browse the filesystem (on OS 7 at least) -- kind of what you'd do with "intents" on android the bb equivalent of which would be CHAPI.